# How to show only 30 rows and hide the remaining rows of QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I'm having a QTableWidget with 10,000 records. I need to show only 30 rows at a time and hide the remaining rows. While dragining/clicking vertical scrollbar it should show corresponding rows and hide the other rows.

ie, if one clicks on upper scroll button it should show one more upper item and hide one lower item and vice versa. It should happen while scrolling as well.

Can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can trap the events of up/down buttons as Nicholas said, for the tracking of slider/scroll bar u need use 'setTracking(true)'followed by the handling of signal either 'valueChanged(int)' or 'sliderMoved(int)'.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Qt unfortunately won't make this easy for you, there is ways and means of doing it however. Depending on how you're populating your widget I'd recommend setting it up so you initially populate your 30 rows, you then need to trap the signals coming from the scroll buttons being clicked and tell the table widget to remove the upper/lower item and add the next one, there's trade off's to this method, but it'll make it easier than trying to maintain a large list of hidden rows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!!
I'm also having the same idea. But how to track the scrollbar while dragging?

Comment: The scrollbar emits that it's moved by <x> amount every time it's dragged, you can connect to that signal as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if explicitly showing/hiding things is the way you want to go.  Instead, take a look at Qt's model and view classes.  If you are using a database, have a look at [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqltablemodel.html), which should handle these things for you.  Otherwise, have a look at the [Model-View programming](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html) document, their [related examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html#related-examples), and especially the portion about [optimizing for performance](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/model-view-programming.html#performance-optimization-for-large-amounts-of-data) (although in a model, 10,000 records isn't really all that many for most uses).

Comment: I'm using csv file instead of Database

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change table scrolling from pixels to items.  In Designer Property Editor for the table, in the **QAbstractItemView**  section, there is a **VerticalScrollMode** selection.  This can either be **ScrollPerPixel** or what you probably want, **ScrollPerItem**.

That may change the behavior of the signal from pixels to items which would make your calculations easier.

I'm using 4.4.3.