# QTableWidget display certain number of rows at a time

Tags: c++, qt

I have a large qtablewidget.  Let's say 200 rows.  In QListWidget, there is setMaxVisibleItems(30), which is extremely useful.  What's the equivalent for a qtablewidget, except for rows.  Ie. setMaxVisibleRows?

I considered setting a max height for my window.  However, this application can be used on varying DPIs.  So, it may be small for some.  Plus, that felt like a needless restriction.

I also saw this: [How to show only 30 rows and hide the remaining rows of QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431800/how-to-show-only-30-rows-and-hide-the-remaining-rows-of-qtablewidget[])

However, it isn't the same by any means.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: For clarification.  Do you want to show, for say, the first 30 rows?  Or do you wanna show rows based on something like a filter?

Comment: To clarify, yeah. The first thirty rows.  As if the user resized the list so that only the first 30 are visible--  the rest are visible via scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I would do it is to use Qt's `void QTableView::setRowHidden(int row, bool hide)`

> void QTableView::setRowHidden(int row, bool hide):
>
> If hide is true row will be hidden, otherwise it will be shown.

If you know the count of your table you can use that othewise you will have to use a `model` and use `rowCount()`.

Then the `for` loop should be easy:

```
for(int i = startHidingHere; i < numOfRows; i++)
    myTable->setRowHidden(i, true);
```

You can obviously do a similar method to un-hide them. This method also works great for filters if needed in the future.

**Other possible useful methods:**

```
bool QTableView::isRowHidden(int row);

void QTableView::setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide);

void QTableView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model);
->   int QAbstractItemModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const
```